# Upload file using node js file empty on linux env

Tags: node.js, symfony

I'm trying to submit an xls file using node js, i tried the code below, it work on my local machine Windows 7 but when deploy on linux environment it send empty file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var req = request.post(base_url + "/api/livraison/import-api", function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error!');
    } else {
        console.log('URL: ' + body);
        console.log('Import COMPLETED');
    }
});
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(path));
```

Server side response :

```
Server responded with: 

object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(23) "model_livraison1804.xls"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpErA4T8"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(9) "phpErA4T8"
}
```

Is there any changes need to be done  createReadStream() in linux environment ?

Thanks

Comment: How is your `path` created? Linux and Windows have differences with paths.

Comment: path is full path of file `var path = __dirname + '/' + 'file.xls';`

Comment: One difference in Windows and Linux is the slash/backslash

Comment: The best way of creating paths in node is to use the path util, which will do its best to create a valid path.

Comment: `var pathutil = require("path")` and then `var path = pathutil.join(__dirname, "file.xls")`

Comment: Tell me if that works and I'll add an aswer with that

Comment: Thanks for the help but still the file is empty from server side, i have no error when submitting with node

Comment: Oh! A small note, the `filename` property is a header, which tells the filename, so you don't have to show the entire path. It has to be `{ filename: filename, contentType: ... }`

Comment: Also. Why do you add the `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` thingy? Is there a reason for that? If you copypasted it from somewhere, try to understand the code you copypasted (like the filename property, for example).

Comment: i followed docs from this [link](https://github.com/form-data/form-data)

Comment: Yes, and the docs don't have any `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`. Content type is to tell the type of the file, and in this case the file is not a multipart form data. The type is a XLS file. I recommend to delete thje headers you are forcing, as the content type is not needed and the filename is when the user is downloading the file, not when uploading to your own server: `form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(path))`

Comment: Thanks again i used `form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(path))` but as mentioned before in windows environment work but in Debian the uploaded file is empty.
Do you have any idea what my be the problem ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make a individual test. To create a node.js file with `fs.createReadStream(path)` and do some checks with the stream received. Maybe try to create a form with other type of data or adding the file in other way than a stream.